# How to click on this webpage button with AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript

I am having trouble clicking on the "search" button on a particular website. The website is a subscription service, so I am attaching a picture of the page pulled up in "inspect" mode as well as my code.

[image: page image]

My code:

```
set myURL to "https://www.uptodate.com/contents/search"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:myURL}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists (UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.3
    end repeat
end tell

inputByID("tbSearch", "myVar")

clickClassName("newsearch-submit", 0)



###InputByID###
to inputByID(theId, theValue)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value ='" & theValue & "';" in document 1
    end tell
end inputByID

###ClickByClass###
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName
```

Comment: If I copy and paste your code in **Script Editor** under **macOS High Sierra** and run it,  the first thing I see  is the `repeat` _loop_  never exits. Replacing it with my own _code_ it waits till it's loaded.  However, even though "myVar" get set as the _value_ of the  `tbSearch` _input field_, the search button is not clicked because the _input field_ is checking for `keyup` and `keydown` _events_, and that not happening just because you've set the _value_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use **UI Scripting**, where **System Events** preforms some *keystrokes*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me in **macOS High Sierra**<sup>1</sup>:

```
set myURL to "https://www.uptodate.com/contents/search"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:myURL}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (accessibility description of ¬
        button 1 of UI element 1 of every group of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
        process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page") contains "Reload this page"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('tbSearch').value ='PPE';" in document 1
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke space
    key code 51 -- # Press the delete key to remove the space.
    keystroke return
end tell
```

- <sup>1</sup> **NOTE:** For **macOS Mojave** and later, change `UI element 1` to `UI element 2` in the `repeat` *loop* above.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and of course not having a subscription cannot truly test it but perhaps you can see if this works for you - it seemed to be working:

```
tell application "Safari"
    --activate --can work with or w/o Safari in foreground
    set myURL to "https://www.uptodate.com/contents/search"
    make new document with properties {URL:myURL}
    delay 5 -- just waits for (hopefully) the page to load
    set d to do JavaScript "document.forms[0][0].value = 'joint pain'" in document 1
    do JavaScript "document.forms['searchForm'].submit();" in document 1

end tell
```

Comment: This did not work for me, that is the `do JavaScript "document.forms['searchForm'].submit();` as all it does is refresh the window and was the first thing I tried before posting an answer using **UI Scripting** and **System Events** to handle it.  Also the use of the `delay` _command_ to wait for the page to finish loading can be inaccurate and why I used the _code_ I did to wait for the page to finish loading, as the _code_ for it in the OP was not working.