# How can I write an applescript to click the Play button on this remote radio station?

Tags: javascript, applescript

I would like to create a script that will go to https://tunein.com/radio/ESPN-Radio-710-s32301/ and click the Play button to start playing, and click it again after 5 minutes to stop playing.
I have no idea how to accomplish this.  I've seen similar questions asked [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718200/how-to-click-on-this-webpage-button-with-applescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999188/can-i-automate-clicking-on-a-specific-button-on-a-website), but in my case I don't know how to identify the button to tell applescript which button to click.

[image: image of the button I want clicked]

I'm horrible at Applescript but I'll take any solution in any language here as long as I have the ability to run it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the `<a>` element, not the `<svg>`:

```
document.querySelector("#appRootScrollReset > div.app-module__content___saRsJ.app-module__leftSideOpen___GC95T > div > div > section.row.profile-module__playSection___HTaII > div > div.profile-module__playButtonContainer___L7UMN > a").click();
```

This code above will trigger the play button.

Ok now, those random letters after those class names makes me a bit uneasy. When the admin generates a new build of the page, those random letters may change. To make the selection more reliable, let's select by XPath instead:

```
document.evaluate(
    `//*[@id="appRootScrollReset"]/div[3]/div/div/section[1]/div/div[3]/a`, 
    document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null
).singleNodeValue.click();
```

This should keep working until the admin changes the actual HTML structure of the page. If the admin does do it, just select the `<a>` element, right click, select Copy XPath and replace the XPath.